# Google Drive/Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-drive-api

Does google drive use the broader google cloud storage infrastructure as it's backend?  If it does is there any way to get the bucket metadata related to a drive account via an api call?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it physically uses the same infrastructure or not, it doesn't logically. There's no bucket corresponding to a user's Drive, at least not publicly.